# emacs - autocompletion in Emacs Lisp mode

Tags: emacs

Recently I've discovered `M-x ielm` (the Emacs self-REPL) and was pleasantly surprised that there's a working tab-completion in that mode. Say, I can start typing `ecb-`, then hit TAB and `ielm` will show me what functions are exposed by ECB. Very convenient for exploration!

However, when I start editing one of my `*.el` files (in Emacs Lisp major mode), TAB no longer works as autocomplete and performs indentation, which I find unfortunate.

I tried to figure out how autocompletion works within `ielm` in order to possibly transplant it into Emacs Lisp mode. However, apparently, autocompletion in `ielm` uses `comint-dynamic-complete`, which, as far as I understand, works only in `comint`-based buffers. I guess, this means that I'm out of luck here.

So, well, how do I enable autocompletion for Emacs Lisp?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In recent versions of Emacs, you can use a little-known piece of built-in functionality which enables TAB completion:

```
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)
(add-to-list 'completion-styles 'initials t)
```

With this setup, `TAB` - which is usually bound to `indent-for-tab-command` - first tries to adjust the indentation according to the mode's settings, but if the indentation is already correct, completion is triggered. This is usually the desired behavior, and IMHO works better than third-party plugins like [smart-tab](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TabCompletion#SmartTab).

Note, however, that in some modes, `TAB` is not bound to `indent-for-tab-command`, so further rebinding is necessary for those modes, e.g. with `smart-tab`. Also, when modes have "bounce indent" (e.g. `python-mode`), this technique will also not work.

Answer (score 3):

I find both indenting and completion helpful at times, so I have a function that chooses based on whether the last thing I did was inserting text or not:

```
(global-set-key [tab] 'indent-or-expand)
(defun indent-or-expand ()
  "Either indent according to mode, or expand the word preceding point."
  (interactive)
  (if (or
       (eq last-command 'self-insert-command)
       (eq last-command 'dabbrev-expand))
      (progn
        (setq this-command 'dabbrev-expand)
        (dabbrev-expand nil))
    (indent-according-to-mode)))
```

You can probably use `comint-dynamic-complete` instead of `dabbrev` if you want, but I find that `dabbrev` works great for emacs lisp - particularly when combined with `completer.el`, which can expand even `f-f-r-o` into `find-file-read-only`.

Comment: Smart idea. Accidentally invoking completion when you just wanted to indent is never a good thing.